# jQuery tab content increases Overlapping content to bottom div

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

Created a jQuery tab content changer when tab content is increasing height due to inner content its overlapping to its bottom div.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
     .mid_content{height:auto;width:1070px;margin:auto;}
     #footer{bottom:0;height: 50px;width: 100%;background-color:    rgb(83,83,83);clear:both; margin: 50px 0 0 0; position:relative;}
 tabs {
    float:left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
div.active{
    background:#999;
    color:#333333;
}
div.tab_container div.active{
    background-color:#FFF;}
/*  di
v.tabs div.active{

} */
.tab_container {
    float:right;
    clear: both;
    height:300px;
    width: 700px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    border-radius:5px;
}

p#con_tab{
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    font:"MS Serif", "New York", serif;
}
.tab_content {
    height:290px;
    width:690px;
    display: none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:5px;
}
#tab1{height:auto;}
#tab2{height:auto;}
#tab3{height:auto;}
#tab4{height:auto;}



 </style> 
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

    $("div.tabs div").click(function() {
        $("div.tabs div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();

        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
});

 </script> 
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="mid_content">
<div class="tab_container"> 
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content active">   
 <p id="con_tab">We aim to provide committed healthcare services to all our patients      through  dedicated research and Committed Clinical Excellence & Successes.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
 <p id="con_tab">Global Medi Consultants has committed itself to spread a healthy smile on all our clients faces.<br /> <br />All our clients are our family and we are committed to providing quality healthcare</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"> 

<p id="con_tab">Global Medi Consultants fill a very important void in the Medical travel domain and provide transparency in both quality of care and pricing.<br /> Our main goal is to provide a safe, affordable, and timely option to healthcare in house and across the globe for unavailable specialties.<br /> More specifically, to assist insured, uninsured, under-insured, or those stuck in long waiting lines to receive their medical treatments. <br /><br />Since long, we have been implementing an organized process of facilitation to our clients. In effect, they receive all the benefits of our knowledge and expertise we have gained over the years.</p>        
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content"> 
 <p id="con_tab">We are committed to the highest ethical, legal and professional standards and work with commitment.<br />                                                      We conduct ourselves with honesty and integrity in our dealings with and on behalf of our clients.<br />
                    We are accountable for our conduct and for compliance with applicable laws.<br />
                    We treat everyone with respect and dignity, and make no distinction based on medical condition, age, gender, disability, race, color, religion, national origin or place of residence.<br />
                    We are committed to the ethical and compassionate treatment of patients and compliance with established policies and statements of patient rights.<br />     <br />
                    We use confidential information only to carry out our work and do not share such information with others unless duly instructed by the patient or required on behalf of the patient.<br /><br />
                    We place the interests of our patients above our own.
                     We deal with patients, payers, vendors, and providers with honesty  and integrity.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs"> 
    <div class="active dash d_one" rel="tab1"><br /><h2>VISION</h2></div>
    <div class="dash d_two" rel="tab2"><br /><h2>MISSION</h2></div>
    <div class="dash d_three" rel="tab3"><h2>WHAT<br />WE DO</h2></div>
    <div class="dash d_four" rel="tab4"><h2>CODE<br />OF <br />CONDUCT</h2></div>

</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is a box which changes content on click of tabs. I'm having trouble with the footer when I select the 4th div, it is overlapping the footer but increasing the page height whether it should scroll down its bottom div means footer 
but it's not sliding it down.

The 4 div I've created are tabs, the tab content is the div aligned with it when clicks on the tab content changes, and the first div is active div.

My footer is common to the rest of my site pages. What CSS or jQuery should I add to make my tabs box work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the wrapper of your content tabs `.tab-container` has `height: 300px;`. Put it to `min-height: 300px;` and it should work fine.

[JsFiddle Test](http://jsfiddle.net/GEA9E/1/)

Comment: I tried its height to min-height but no effect has made on it.

Comment: If you check the code on the test I provided is the same as in your example. I do not know if you have something else influencing the behavior, but it should work.